# Where are added archetypes stored in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

When creating a Maven-based project/module in IDEA you can click "Add archetype".  Where are these new archetype values stored?  I looked in my ~/.m2/repository but I don't think that's it…

Bonus question: what are the best practices around "Add archetype"?  Just curious.  I'm prone to skipping this in IDEA and just using mvn from the command line.

Answer (score 53):

The information about added archetypes are stored in the file

Linux: `~/.IntelliJIdea10/system/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml`

Mac: `~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml`

You can edit this file directly. You need to restart IntelliJ after editing this file. There is no other way at this point in time to modify this information, see issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-60985

The archetype plugins will be downloaded to your local repository.

Comment: Why did I get a negative score on this answer? I would like to know the reason since I put much time in investigating this. If it is not the answer to the question, then what is the question exactly, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Your answer is still very much correct in IntelliJ Idea versions 11 and 12. The paths have only slightly modified to :

~/.IdeaIC11/system/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml and
~/.IdeaIC12/system/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml

Idea still needs to be restarted for these changes to take effect.

Comment: On a Mac, the path is ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/Maven/Indices/UserArchetypes.xml

Answer (score 7):

And in Windows (7) you'll find them here: `C:\Users\<username>\.IdeaI<versionid>\system\Maven\Indices\UserArchetypes.xml`

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 (2020):

Looks like newer versions of IntelliJ have switched to AppData folder.

> `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdealC<version>\Maven\Indices`

In Windows 10 (Older versions):

> `C:\Users\<username>\.IntelliJIdea<version>\system\Maven\Indices`

Comment: Looks like newer versions of IntelliJ have switched to AppDatafolder.
 `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdealC2020.1\Maven\Indices`

Answer (score 0):

intelliJ OSX: (vers. 2020.1)

cd ~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/Maven/Indices/

Comment: for windows 10 intellij 2020, the file can be found in C:\Users\username\appdata\local\jetbrains\idealc2020.1\maven\indices